# auto-connect-retry="true" attribute in spring mongo 1.10 xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mongo

When upgrading the mongo java driver to 3.4.2 the spring mongo dependency was updated to 1.10. The xml configuration doesn't have an attribute for auto-connect-retry to be set to true.Is there an alternative for that.

```
<mongo:client-options connections-per-host="10" threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="10"
connect-timeout="1000" max-wait-time="1500" read-preference="PRIMARY"
socket-keep-alive="true" socket-timeout="1500"/>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23296665/421642

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB Java driver: autoConnectRetry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295333/mongodb-java-driver-autoconnectretry)